# Mapbox filters and tabbed tooltips not working together

Tags: mapbox

I'm a bit new to this, but i have created a map with an option to filter the markers, as well as tabbed tooltips.

On page load, the tabbed tooltips work, but when I click on the filter buttons and then click on the marker again, the tabs (and the content I included with the tabs) are not showing up. I have to refresh the page to get the tabs to show up again.

The orange icon is the one I was playing around with and is the only one that has tabs at the moment.

Why do the tabs not work after I click on a filter button?

[A JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asrgxtpv/1/)

My code:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.wwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxssssssss';
// In the propeties object for each marker define key's
// like `rentals`, `fuel`, `tackleshop` that are set to true for false
// depending on whether or they exist at a location.

var geoJson = [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
        -84.519253,39.116177
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Findlay Market (North Lot)",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": true,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
         -84.518411,39.114629
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Findlay Market (East Lot)",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": true,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.520621,39.114837
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Findlay Market (West Lot)",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": true,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.510765,39.110845
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "ABM Parking",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.518343,39.109173
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Washington Park (Elm Entrance)",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": true,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
           -84.516762,39.109543
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Washington Park (Race Entrance)",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": true,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.510899,39.109465
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "OTR Parking / Neon's",
        "cashaccepted": false,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": false,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.511513,39.108121

        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Central Parking - Maint St.",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.518547,39.108793
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Central Parking - Memorial Hall",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.516638,39.107744

        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Over The Rhine Public Parking",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": false,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://www.wakeupcoffee.biz/images/icon_car03b.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }
    },


    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -84.515022,39.110240
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "information": {
            "Information": "<p><b>Mercer Garage</b></p> <hr> <div style='float:left; margin-top:5px;'>1324 Vine St.<br>Cincinnati, OH 45202</div> <div style='float:right; width:100px; margin-top:5px; background-color:#3d54a5; color:white; text-align: center; padding:6px 0px 6px 0px; border-radius: 4px;'>  Get Directions </div>  <br><br><br><hr> <div style='margin-top:5px;'><b>Phone:</b>(513)381-5800</div>     ",
            "Rates": "<div>$1/hour, up to an $8 maximum</div> <div>Monday – Friday after 4pm: $5</div> <div>All day Saturday – Sunday: $5<div><br><div>Monthly parking passes are available for $85/month</div>",
            "Images": "<iframe src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1433855519514!6m8!1m7!1sI_zlWDFRpn2L2r1DmPeRBw!2m2!1d39.110841!2d-84.510429!3f276.4279292294492!4f-11.08512964773044!5f0.4000000000000002' width='350' height='250' frameborder='0' style='border:0'></iframe>",
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Mercer Garage",
        "cashaccepted": true,
        "creditcardsaccepted": true,
        "indoorgarage": true,
        "monthlyrates": false,
        "open24": true,
        "outdoorlots": false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://static.nationwide.com/static/icon-opt-link-car-orange.gif?r=47",
            "iconSize": [35, 35], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [17,-5], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
      }



    }
];








var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'motrpub.3bbda9ac', { zoomControl: false })
    .setView([39.112, -84.514], 16);

new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

var markers = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .setGeoJSON(geoJson)
    .addTo(map);




// START CUSTOM ICON //

markers.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;

    marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
});

// Add features to the map.
markers.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

// END CUSTOM ICON //


var info = document.getElementById('info');

// Iterate through each feature layer item,
// and create a custom HTML group for each. In this example
// we create a tabs menu and put each property in a respective tab.
markers.eachLayer(function(m) {
    // Shorten m.feature.properties to p for convenience.
    var p = m.feature.information;

    var tabs = document.createElement('div');
    tabs.className = 'tabs-ui';

    for (var key in p) {
        var tab = document.createElement('div');
        tab.className = 'tab';

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'radio';
        input.id = idify(key);
        input.name = 'tab-group'; // For your own needs, you might want this to be unique.
        if (key === 'Information') input.setAttribute('checked', true);

        tab.appendChild(input);

        tab.innerHTML += '<label for=' + idify(key) + '>' + key + '</label>' +
        '<div class="content">' +
            p[key] +
        '</div>';

        tabs.appendChild(tab);
    }

    m.bindPopup(tabs, {minWidth: 400});

});



function idify(str) { return str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); };




$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');


    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    markers.setFilter(function(f) {
        // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
        // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
        // a value set to true based on the filter name.
        return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;

    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe `setFilter` runs a `clearLayers` on your markers `featureLayer`, which wipes out your bound popups.I moved the popup binding into a function(`setBinds`) which runs on init, and after every `setFilter`, and now I believe it works as you intended. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/asrgxtpv/3/